# Why building the same project generates different EXE file for each developer

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, linker, binary-reproducibility

My team and I are developing a VC++ 6 project.
We are all using the same code-base (using version control system), and all our compiler/linker/environment-settings (including include directories order), as far as we can tell, are exactly the same.
Of course we are using the same VC++ version with the same service packs (VC6 SP6).

The problem is that the EXE that each one of us build is a little bit different.

**I know that every time you build an EXE on the same computer, there are 3 locations in the file where the linker stores a time-stamp. I'm not talking about these differences.**

Though our EXE files are exactly the same length, when we compare the EXEs, **there are 1000's of bytes that differs. Many of those bytes differs by 0x20 in value.**

Any idea what may be the reason?

Edit: Debug build (Actually, We didn't check the release).

Edit: The differences are in binary sections, not in text-strings.

Edit: All of the developers are using the same drive/folder names, for source and for products.

Comment: I assume that you're asking about the release version, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Debug` version has the option "Link incrementally" checked, then probably it's the reason for the diffs.

Comment: it's just a guess. Incremental linking adds some debug info every time you build the project. It doesn't create a *clean* exe.

Comment: I'll check it on Sunday. Thank you.

Comment: D: Thank you! Rebuild All by all developers did generate the same EXE (except from time tag differences).

Comment: @Lior, yes, Rebuild All creates a clean EXE. I should have mentioned it. So, that was indeed the problem? I'm glad I could help. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Since 0x20 is the difference between upper and lower case ASCII characters I wonder if these differences happen to be in file paths that the compiler/linker embed in the binary (assert messages perhaps?).  Could your dev trees be different ("C:\DevTrees\MyProject\SuperFoo" on one box and "E:\work\projects\superfoo" on another?).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what NickD says. During debug, incremental linking is on which doesn't rebuild the exe from scratch, but appends/inserts/removes code here and there for each build.

I.e. the layout of the exe depends on every compilation since the first.

A clean build should yield identical results on identical compilers.

Answer (score 1):

It might be coincidence, but 0x20 is the difference between the values of lower-case and upper-case ASCII characters (eg 'A' == 65 == 0x41, 'a' == 97 = 0x61).

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: uninitialized parts of strings or string properties of a certain length where the #0 is not at the end ?